# Building problem: A required package was not found

Tags: github, kinect, ros, lidar

I tried install to s300 library(cob_sick_s300) on ros kinetic  and I've been stuck on the cmake step.

Here the full log, do you have an idea ?

```
    -- Found the following Boost libraries:
    --   filesystem
    --   thread
    --   system
    --   chrono
    --   date_time
    --   atomic
    -- Checking for module 'libvlc'
    --   No package 'libvlc' found
    CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.5/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:367 (message):
      A required package was not found
    Call Stack (most recent call first):
      /usr/share/cmake-3.5/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:532 (_pkg_check_modules_internal)
      cob_driver/cob_mimic/CMakeLists.txt:7 (pkg_check_modules)


    -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
    See also "/home/tarik/s300_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
    See also "/home/tarik/s300_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
    Invoking "cmake" failed
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following code.

```
sudo apt-get install libvlccore-dev
sudo apt-get install libvlc-dev
```

By right, this should give you the vlc library needed.

If still can not find, then high chance you did sth in .bashrc or PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment setting.

Follow this link to install correct path under **Linking against libVLC** section

https://wiki.videolan.org/LibVLC_Tutorial/