# Flutter linux build failed

Tags: linux, flutter, dart, cmake

I am getting this message, I don't know what it actually mean. Any help would appreciated.

```bash
CMake Error at /snap/flutter/126/usr/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:419 (message):
  A required package was not found
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /snap/flutter/126/usr/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:597 (_pkg_check_modules_internal)
  flutter/ephemeral/.plugin_symlinks/desktop_webview_auth/linux/CMakeLists.txt:21 (pkg_check_modules)


Building Linux application...                                           
Exception: Unable to generate build files
```

Comment: I tried to rebuild my project but nothing works.

Comment: Name of the missed package is one line **above** the error message and looks like `No package 'FOO' found`. E.g. the log in [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56661882/building-problem-a-required-package-was-not-found) tells about missed package `libvlc`.

Comment: I had the same issue. Checkout this solution [from](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73913474/cmake-error-at-snap-flutter-126-usr-share-cmake-3-10-modules-findpkgconfig-cmak).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with the `desktop_webview_auth` the build requires something that the package doesn't have .

you have to open an issue on github to get more information from the developers of the package as there is no info in the error

Comment: but i have used webview anywhere and previously the app was running in linux.

Comment: can you provide the whole error code from terminal ?

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I was able to previous version of this application. That didn't have any of this issue. although I have created this issue in flutter repo as well. lets see what will be the reply

Answer (score 1):

For me, I had to install `webkit2gtk` package.

For example on Arch linux: `yay -S webkit2gtk`

Comment: yo man. thanks but I have figured the question out. Some library was messing my code. I have to get actual working code. Maybe what you saying is correct but I can't check it now. I am upvoting your answer but can't accept the answer because above guy actually told me to check for dependency. thanks for stackoverflowing.