# CMake Error at /snap/flutter/126/usr/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:419 Flutter Linux

Tags: linux, flutter, cmake

I am trying to use the [FirebaseCoreDesktop](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_core_desktop) and [FirebaseAuthDesktop](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_auth_desktop) packages in my Flutter Project for linux (ubuntu). Unfortunatly when trying to run the App, I am getting the following Error.

```
CMake Error at /snap/flutter/126/usr/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:419 (message):
  A required package was not found
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /snap/flutter/126/usr/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:597 (_pkg_check_modules_internal)
  flutter/ephemeral/.plugin_symlinks/desktop_webview_auth/linux/CMakeLists.txt:21 (pkg_check_modules)
```

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Were you following all [the official linux setup instructions](https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/install/linux#linux-setup) already when you encountered this error? Or did you encounter this because you weren't following the instructions? The current instructions say to install `libgtk-3-dev`.

Comment: I did install it but the problem i had was using the flutter sdk from (snap). I changed it to the git sdk and everything worked fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution.

Run

```
sudo apt install libwebkit2gtk-4.0-dev -y
```

and I had to uninstall flutter(snap) and install the [Flutter](https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git) git version in directory of your choice.

```
git clone https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
```

As said in [DesktopWebviewAuth](https://pub.dev/packages/desktop_webview_auth).
And then change flutter SDK path to the one you cloned and remove the build folder from my project.

Answer (score 0):

if you use fedora

```
sudo dnf install webkit2gtk3-devel
```

and reboot your computer.